# Html table padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image, html-table

I have a problem with bootstrap tables. I am using images with 7 columns, but right of the images have a empty area. How can I fix this?

[image: It's the table. Look at the right of the squares.]

Comment: See [ask]. You should show a [mcve] and explain exactly what you are trying to do, and show what results you get. Sicne you are using Bootstrap you should open your pages in any browser with developer mode enabled and inspect the objects to find out why your containers are the size they are. This looks like your content is smaller than the container, and it is being rendered floating to the left. Easy to test with developer mode.

Comment: Can you help me sir? Its the test server: cantest.ga

Comment: No one can really help you until you provide us with the details that all questions need, as per [ask].

Comment: Should I add html codes?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. So this might be HTML, CSS, whatever is being used to generate and style those containers.